# Static constexpr global variable

Tags: c++, static, global-variables, constants, constexpr

In C++17, is there any difference between declaring a global constant like this:

```
namespace ns
{
static constexpr const auto global_variable = 47;
}
```

Specifying the `const` modifier as well, and:

```
namespace ns
{
static constexpr auto global_variable = 47;
}
```

Without specifying `const`? If yes, which are the differences and which version of the declaration is recommended in which scenarios?

Comment: In C++17 you may as well define a global constant `inline` rather than `static`. Or just in an anonymous namespace.

Comment: In the examples given, no.  But `static constexpr char* global_variable = "Happy";` applies the `constexpr` to the _type_ `char*`, which is as-if it was `char* const`.  And that's not what you really want.  So there you need to do `static constexpr char const* global_variable = "Happy";`.

Comment: @DeiDei well it is already in a `namspace`, what are the benefits of making it `inline` instead of `static` in my example case?

Answer (score 7):

There is no difference, the `constexpr` specifier on a variable of object type implies `const` [[dcl.constexpr]/9](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.constexpr#9):

> A `constexpr` specifier used in an object declaration declares the object as `const`. […]

Note that the `static` is redundant here as well because the const-qualified type already implies internal linkage [[basic.link]/3.2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.link#3.2):

> A name having namespace scope has internal linkage if it is the name of
>
> - […]
> - non-inline variable of non-volatile const-qualified type that is neither explicitly declared `extern` nor previously declared to have external linkage […]
> - […]

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to have `const` here, `constexpr` implies `const`.